# Search within files in search result in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

I often use Sublime Text 2's `search all open files/folders` feature (CMD+SHIFT+F).

Is it possible to perform a second search that only queries files which contain the first search query?

For example: `Search 1` finds 5 files that contain "hello". `Search 2` should only query those same 5 files for "world", so the resulting matches will be files which contain both "hello" and "world".

I can search the text which is visible in the results buffer (such as in the screenshot below), but I'd like to search the entire contents of all files that are shown in the results buffer.

[image: content-top clearfix]

Comment: (CMD+P) to open the files and then search (CMD+F)

Comment: CMD+P does not open the files. It opens some 'dropdown' like menu

Comment: please try `Ctrl + F` to search text in current file..

Comment: Did you have any luck with the method I posted?

Answer (score -1):

## 1:

Open the `find_in_files` panel with <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>.

In the example, `<open folders>` is used for the `Where:` argument, but you can use whatever fits your initial search criteria.

[image: Step1]

---

## 2:

Open the `find` panel with <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> while you are still in the results buffer.

Enter `^(/Users/.*)(?=:$)` as your `Find:` argument, and make sure the `RegEx` switch is enabled. This `RegEx` pattern will match all of the paths within the results.
( *Windows users can enter* `^(C:\\.*)(?=:$)` )

Copy the selected paths.

[image: Step2]

---

## 3:

Paste the copied paths into a blank document.

Open the `replace` panel with <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>.

Enter `^(/Users/.*)(\n)` as the `Find What:` argument, and `$1$2,`  as the `Replace With:` argument. This will effectively convert all of the lines into a single line of comma separated values.
( *Windows users can enter* `^(C:\\.*)(\n)` )

[image: Step3-1]

Copy the resulting line.

[image: Step3-2]

---

## 4:

Open the `find_in_files` panel with <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>.

Paste the copied path list as your `Where:` argument, and enter your second query as the `Find:` argument.

[image: Step4]

---

## 5:

Repeat as necessary.